# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Type Query must define one or more fields

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

this my code

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query 
  type Mutation {
    id: ID!
    text: String!
  }
`;
```

I only have mutations, I don’t need Query.i get error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Type Query must define one or more fields.

How can I declare an empty Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Root-Operation-Types):

> A schema defines the initial root operation type for each kind of operation it supports: query, mutation, and subscription; this determines the place in the type system where those operations begin.
>
> **The query root operation type must be provided and must be an Object type.**
>
> The mutation root operation type is optional; if it is not provided, the service does not support mutations. If it is provided, it must be an Object type.

[Additionally](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Objects):

> An Object type must define one or more fields.

So a query root operation type **must** be provided, it **must** be an Object type and, as a result, it **must** include at least one field.

You'll need to provide at least one `field` for Query, even if it's never used and always just returns null.