# Type query_root must define one or more fields

Tags: hasura

First, thanks Hasura for incredible good product! I love it.

I have issue with derive action with Hasura Console. My use case:

- I enable anonymous role for subscribe function (everybody can send email to subscribe)
- I have configured permission on my subscribe table, everything is fine.
- I want to validate the user input on server side, for example, validate email format. I have followed by [this guide about derive action](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/actions/derive.html). I found no mistake here.
- But I got the error "Type query_root must define one or more fields." when I hit "Derive action" at the first time.
- According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839398/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-error-type-query-must-define-one-or-more-fiel), as I understand, I need to have object type for root query.

Of course, I will have object type for root query eventually. I can work around by giving some dummy queries for anonymous role. But I do not like that cheat anyway.

Any idea on that? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Edited:
My related current version:

- Hasura 1.3.2
- One click deployment using Docker on Digital Ocean.